# Device Capture with VLCJ

Tags: java, vlc, libvlc, vlcj

I'm trying to use VLCJ for video capture with webcams (USB & IP)

dshow:// & rtsp://192.168.1.4:554/live.sdp

works like a charm with VLC 2.0.1 x64 Windows 7.

but nothing works with VLCJ 2.1.0 examples

Java SE 1.7 x64

RTSP error :

```
[000000000fefed58] main demux error: corrupt module: C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\plugins\demux\liblive555_plugin.dll
[000000000059a4d8] main input error: open of `rtsp://192.168.1.4:554/live.spd' failed
[000000000059a4d8] main input error: Your input can't be opened
[000000000059a4d8] main input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'rtsp://192.168.1.4:554/live.spd'. Check the log for details.
```

Dshow error :

```
[00000000004fa4d8] main input error: open of `dshow://' failed
[00000000004fa4d8] main input error: Your input can't be opened
[00000000004fa4d8] main input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'dshow://'. Check the log for details.
```

Any Ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: Increase the logging level and attach the output. Without that information it's hard to tell much.

Comment: Also, are you sure your libraries (including plugins) are compiled for the right architecture? You need to have 64-bit DLLs if you're calling them from a 64-bit JVM, but the 64-bit builds of libvlc for windows are supposedly only experimental. If you want better stability you should probably get a 32-bit JVM and 32-bit libvlc binaries.

Comment: Yes I was sure of all that, I guess x64 is still a "no mans land" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found the solution. I had the same problem as you with trying to run dshow://. I think the problem was vlc2.0.1 x64 which is experimental. I simply run this using 32bit configration (32bit java, 32bit vlc) and it works perfectly.