# Can't get VLCJ CaptureTest to work

Tags: java, webcam, vlcj

I need to be able to record from my webcam in the Java application I'm programming. I've tried JMF but couldn't get the Capture Device (it only *saw* the audio devices). Right now I'm trying with VLCJ and it just doesn't work. If I open the VLC Player I can access the camera with no problem at all, so I know my webcam works because and that I should be able to make it work through VLCJ. I just don't know how.

The code is the same in the CaptureTest.java file available here:

http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/wiki/SimpleExamples

all I did was try it with a String "dshow://" as mrl.

Im on Windows 7, JDK 1.6, VLC 2.1 and Netbeans 7.1

Any ideas?
Thank you very much to anyone who can help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

Are all of the components 32-bit?  (Windows, Java 6, & VLC).  It should also work if all components are 64-bit, but this user was only able to get things working after after switching everything to 32-bit:

- [Device Capture with VLCJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839017/device-capture-with-vlcj)